# Migrating from TFS to Redmine

Tags: redmine, issue-tracking

My team currently is using TFS 2010 for source control, builds and project management.  We are moving to Git for source control, Cruise for builds, and Redmine for project management.  We are using Git-Tfs right now to integrate our source control with TFS, and cruise is a pretty trivial setup, my question is about project management migration.

Are there any processes or tools to migrate the issues, bugs, tasks, and user stories from TFS to Redmine?  Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Depending on how and what you wan't to migrate it could be no more then a couple of Sql insert statements on a migrated database.

Comment: This is a bit of archeology but @James if you made the migration I would be very interested in how. We're doing mostly the same plan (substituting Jenkins for Cruise).

Comment: @RicardoGomes I did not get anywhere with this, and I ended up changing jobs shortly after this.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Really when it comes to importing into Redmine the best bet is to use the REST API (http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api_with_ruby). This requires that you export your data from TFS in some way (best bet is as a csv or tsv) and with a little ruby code iterate through your data and make new issues.

I don't know what tools TFS has built in for exporting data, but as a csv isn't uncommon, and at the least with access to the SQL back-end and an SQL script you could create a csv manually.

The import into Redmine normally requires coding, but there are plugins as well (http://www.redmine.org/plugins/issue_importer_xls).